# I didn't pin that

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, chat-pins

I was looking through a chat transcript, and wanted to see a message's revision history. So, I clicked the arrow, and saw something interesting:

[image: star and pin]

I did star the message, but I did not pin it (I am neither a room owner in that room nor a moderator, so I can't pin messages there). Furthermore, the message is not pinned.

[Here's a permalink to the message in question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28943730#28943730).